# JMeter - How to validate file extension is Invalid after RegEx and log it

Tags: jmeter

Response Data:
NAME    dBob11234aa.doc

I used RegEx: NAME(.*?).(doc)$ this matches as expected, however, how can I log the result if it is Invalid. (i.e. file extension = *.txt).

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) which supports [Perl-Compatible-Regular-Expressions](https://www.pcre.org/) in "Contains" and "Matches" modes.

1. Add Response Assertion as a child of the request which returns this `NAME dBob11234aa.doc` response data
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Matches`
   - Pattern: `NAME(.*?).(doc)$`

     [image: JMeter Response Assertion]
3. That should be it, in case if file extension will not match your regular expression you will get failure like:

   [image: JMeter Response Assertion Regex]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to validate is to put [response assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved). There you can specify what you need to check in the response. To log it in a file, you can use "Assertion Results" or "View Results Tree" or "Simple Data Writer" and it will log the assertion result in the csv. Check below images for reference.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.